# Can't install Azure AD Connect Cloud Sync silently without user interaction

Tags: azure, powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am trying to follow this guide to install Azure AD Connect Cloud Sync using Powershell, ideally silently without user interaction:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/how-to-install-pshell

When trying to connect using the following commands, a login window opens instead of accepting my credentials.

```
$globalAdminPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Global admin password" -AsPlainText -Force     
$globalAdminCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ("GlobalAdmin@contoso.onmicrosoft.com", $globalAdminPassword)     
Connect-AADCloudSyncAzureAD -Credential $globalAdminCreds
```

I need to automate this so I don't understand why the credential I pass in this function don't seem to do anything and I get prompted with a login screen.

Any idea? I tried some powershell commands like NonInteractive or WindowStyle hidden, but no luck.

Comment: Found the problem! My password had a special character "`" which was disappearing using the above command. I found the difference using Get-Credential instead and converting the secure string back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! My password had a special character "`" which was disappearing using the above command. I found the difference using Get-Credential instead and converting the secure string back... This script shows the problem :

```
$PASSWORD = "Specialchar:(`)"
$globalAdminPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $PASSWORD
[System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new("", $globalAdminPassword).Password
Specialchar:()
```

So I guess the connect function was failing because of a bad password but this was not very clear.